# Why is MySQL command line so fast vs. Python?

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql

I need to migrate data from MySQL to Postgres. It's easy to write a script that connects to MySQL and to Postgres, runs a select on the MySQL side and inserts on the Postgres side, but it is veeeeery slow (I have + 1M rows). It's much faster to write the data to a flat file and then import it.

The MySQL command line can download tables pretty fast and output them as tab-separated values, but that means executing a program external to my script (either by executing it as a shell command and saving the output to a file or by reading directly from the stdout). I am trying to download the data using Python instead of the MySQL client.

Does anyone know what steps and calls does the MySQL command line perform to query a large dataset and output it to stdout? I thought it could be just that the client is in C and should be much faster than Python, but the Python binding for MySQL is itself in C so... any ideas?

Comment: Inserting is slower so the comparison is not fair

Comment: The question should be about querying the data using the MySQL CLI vs. using a Python library. To insert the data COPY is indeed much faster

Comment: Then I don't get what you're asking. Your title is about MySQL command-line client vs. Python, but insert vs. read from file into Postgres seems to be a substantial amount of your time difference?

Comment: The time difference between executing a SELECT statement and outputing it to a file using the mysql command line client vs. using the Python library (which is basically connecting to the server and iterating through the data rows).

Comment: Not related to the performance question, but you should try `mysqldump` with the `--compatible=postgresql` argument.

Comment: That is a very nice idea Klaus

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem is that you are inserting each row in a separate transaction (which is the default behavior when you run SQL-queries without explicitly starting a transaction). In that case, the database must write (flush) changes to disk on every `INSERT`. It can be 100x times slower than inserting data in a single transaction. Try to run `BEGIN` before importing data and `COMMIT` after.